# Double click html text to change it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a two columned HTML table which I want to translate from English to Greek.
I desire to do that by double-clicking the `Click to translate` placeholder under the Greek column and then being prompted there, to insert a Greek text instead it.
In other words, I would interact with the HTML file to translate where the placeholder, right from web browser.
Any such (raw data) change should saved in the HTML file directly, without involving database programs such as a *MySQL*; thus, this program is aimed to be HTML-CSS-JS only.

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <section class="allEnglishSections">
            <h2>Conditioning</h2>
            <table>
                <tr><th>English</th><th>Greek</th></tr>
                <tr><td>if</td><td class="changeable">Click to translate</td></tr>
                <tr><td>than</td><td class="changeable">Click to translate</td></tr>
                <tr><td>else</td><td class="changeable">Click to translate</td></tr>
            </table>
        </section>

        <script>
            
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

**From searching data on how to achieve this, I understand I should use something similar to this pseudocode:**

```
document.querySelectorAll(".changeable").addEventListener(ondblclick, function() {
    myTranslation = prompt();
    document.querySelector(".changeable").value = myTranslation;
}
```

But it is unclear to me how to actually selecting all text of a cell by double clicking it, and then changing it directly from web browser in such a way that the HTML file would change.

Is this even possible with latest ECMAScript and if so how will you achieve this?

Comment: as far as I am aware, a NodeList is not the same thing as a jquery equivalent of `$('.changeable')` -- you need to iterate over each one manually and add the event listener to each one. Also, you need to change your `ondblclick` to a string, and remove the 'on' prefix

Comment: @Jhecht is right. I've updated my solution with the code required to iterate over a NodeList object.

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but the example shows translating "if", "than", "else", which is an odd threesome to translate. I would expect "if", "then", "else", but maybe I've been programming too much ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy system would be to create a textarea inside the HTML on double click, and whenever you experience either the blur event or a specific key combination to remove the textarea and swapping it with a text node of it's own value.

Please note that I am added the events onto the `tbody` element. This is done because most events bubble up, and this way no matter how many `<tr>` elements get added in dynamically, I will have the same functionality without having to loop over the nodelist and add the event one-by-one.

I also use `focusout` instead of `blur` for a similar reason: `blur` does not bubble up, but `focusout` does.

**Note** The current version using the `localStorage` won't work on StackOverflow due to sandboxed permissions and so on. Copy/Paste the values into something like JSFiddle or Codepen to see a working example. I personally tested it on [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/btvmxd78/) in case you want to look at it.

I also did not use an example with AJAX/XHR as you seem relatively new to Javascript, and that needs for you to look up how REST APIs / XHR work. Feel free to make another question once you've done some fiddling with those, but for now that felt a bit out-of-scope for this question.

```js
// get items from storage. if nothing is there originally we will get a null value
const fromStorage = localStorage.getItem('definitions');
// null values are falsey, so if it is null we need to use our default. 
// otherwise we just JSON.parse the values we retrieved
const definitions = !fromStorage ? {
  "if": null,
  "when": null,
  "tomato": null,
} : JSON.parse(fromStorage);
// I don't feel like running this command everytime I need to reference the tbody,
// thus, the reference to it here.
const tbody = document.querySelector('#definitions');

// adding an event listener on the tbody means that any of the same event that bubble up from it's children will reach here. 
// This means you can add children in dynamically without needing to worry so long as they have
// a data-editorShown attribute

tbody.addEventListener('dblclick', e => {
  const parent = e.target.parentElement;
  // if somehow the event gets called from something that is NOT one of the TDs, we don't need to go any further from there.
  // sidenote, all values in the Element.dataset are read as strings. you can set them to be whatever
  // but when you read them, they will be strings.
  if (parent.tagName !== 'TR' || parent.dataset.editorShown === 'true') return;
  // The editor is now shown, so let's set that
  parent.dataset.editorShown = true;

  // get the last TD, which is where we will put our textarea
  const dataTd = parent.querySelector('td:last-child');
  // create a new textarea element
  const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
  // the textarea gets some class
  textarea.classList.add('full');
  // and a placeholder
  textarea.placeholder = "Double click to translate";

  // the arguments for this function are backwards to me, but I think it's self explanatory what's happening
  dataTd.replaceChild(textarea, dataTd.firstChild);
  // get that focus on the textarea.
  dataTd.firstChild.focus();

});

function blurOrKeypress(e) {
  // split up largely for readability
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'TEXTAREA') return false;
  if (e.type === 'keypress' && e.code != 'Enter' && !e.ctrlKey) return false;

  // a parent, a row, and a newly minted text node walk into a bar...
  const parent = e.target.parentElement;
  const row = parent.parentElement;
  const text = document.createTextNode(e.target.value || 'Double click to translate');
  /* .isConnected refers to it's state in the DOM. this was some work to try and stop an error that was 
   ocurring due to this being simultaneously the 'blur' 'keypress' event handler. Alas, it didn't.
    If the error is really an issue, then wrapping the parent.replaceChild in a try/catch block should solve it for you.*/
  if (e.target.isConnected) {
    // use the dataset key + the textarea's value to update the definitions.
    definitions[row.dataset.key] = e.target.value;
    // write those to the local storage
    localStorage.setItem('definitions', JSON.stringify(definitions));

    // Or, if you are using a database, you would use some variety of AJAX/XHR call here.

    // get rid of our text element
    parent.replaceChild(text, e.target);
    // reset the editorshown value in case we need to update this again
    row.dataset.editorShown = false;

  }

}
// the one thing I miss about jquery event listeners: adding multiple types of event by putting spaces
tbody.addEventListener('keypress', blurOrKeypress);
tbody.addEventListener('focusout', blurOrKeypress);

// gets the key/value pairs and maps them
tbody.append(...Object.entries(definitions).map(([word, translation]) => {

  // table row, key TD and value TD cells.
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  const keyTd = document.createElement('td');
  const valueTd = document.createElement('td');

  // editor is not shown by default
  tr.dataset.editorShown = false;
  // we use this in an upper function.
  tr.dataset.key = word;

  // add the bold class just for visual interest. you do not need to do this.
  keyTd.classList.add('bold');
  // set the inner text to our word
  keyTd.innerText = word;

  // if it's already set, great! use that. otherwise, 'double click to translate'
  valueTd.innerText = translation || 'Double click to translate';
  // add these two values to our newly minted tr tag.
  tr.append(keyTd, valueTd);
  // return the TR tag so that the above tbody.append gets an element to actually append
  return tr;
}));
```

```css
/* Styling here to make myself feel better*/

textarea.full {
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

td.bold {
  font-style: unset;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  color: #111;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  font-style: italic;
}

th {
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  border-width: 0 0 2px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-style: unset;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Word/Phrase</th>
      <th>Translation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="definitions">
    <!-- HTML generated later -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'll work on an example using `contentEditable` when I come back to comment this when I wake up. Hope it helps in the meantime.

Comment: Hello; thank you dearly; how do save the input? I click enter and I get a line break or a double click the input itself and it doesn't get saved...

Comment: Effectively you would need to save those changes either in a database, or by using some variety of 1) cookie or 2) localStorage. Give me a second and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hello, I thank you for the changes; I just ran the linked JSfiddle; I double clicked a placeholder and edited it but I still can't save the new value by hitting Enter or double click on the new value or near it... How did you save it? Thank you,

Comment: @ShadowyShade unsure what you mean. If you're asking about what key combination i use to save, it's control+enter (windows keyboard). If you're asking about how _you_ should save it in your app, well that's up to you. A database, a backend, and some Ajax/XHR would be necessary.

Comment: I am sorry for the "unaccepting" - your answer is the closest to what I desire to achieve and indeed was the most helpful for me personally so far.

Comment: Jhecht, I tried to click CTRL+Enter but I still can't "permanently" change `Double click to translate` to `something else`. I mean, I can't save the change done after double clicking the placeholder --- into the HTML.

Comment: I humbly try to clarify that I don't want to involve an external database such as MySQL in this HTML-CSS-JS program; I am to have an HTML-CSS-JS only program and saving the raw data (which should replace the placeholders) directly in the HTML; nothing less nothing more,

Comment: All was written kindly and with great appreciation of your help !

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "permanently" save. This is not a full solution -- it is only meant to show you the general steps, as I do not know what your application looks like outside of this question. can you not get the screen to look like this? https://i.imgur.com/VmXq7Gf.png

Comment: I re-read your post -- Javascript _cannot_ alter the data in the HTML file outside of DOM manipulation and some usage of either cookies or local storage. If you are expecting the file to be saved such that if you opened it up in a code editor you would see the translations that _will not_ happen.

Comment: I no longer have the code I wrote; beyond that; yes, it seems to understood me totally --- I did expect the file would changed as if it was edited with a text editor. Sadly I read it cannot happen. Thank you ! I can award bounty in 16 hours.

Comment: Node JS (which is Javascript technically) _could_ alter the back end, but Node does not work in-browser, so you would still need some kind of server to allow for those changes.

Answer (score 1):

*( UPDATED: See last section. )*

One way of doing this, is to create an object which maps english words to greek words, and then add an eventlistener that catches the double click event on the table element, checks if the 'click to translate' element has been clicked and do the translation:

```js
const dict = {
  if: "αν",
  than: "από",
  else: "αλλιώς"
}

document.querySelector("table").addEventListener("dblclick", function(e){
  // Check if the .changeable element has triggered the click event
  if ( e.target.classList.contains("changeable")){
    // Get the text content from the sibling element which contains the english word
    const word = e.target.previousElementSibling.textContent; 
    // Check if we have the word in our dictionary
    if ( dict[word] ){
      // Change the text content of the 'click to translate' element with the greek word
      e.target.textContent = dict[word];
    }
  }
});
```

```css
table {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
        <section class="allEnglishSections">
            <h2>Conditioning</h2>
            <table>
                <tr><th>English</th><th>Greek</th></tr>
                <tr><td>if</td><td class="changeable">Click to translate</td></tr>
                <tr><td>than</td><td class="changeable">Click to translate</td></tr>
                <tr><td>else</td><td class="changeable">Click to translate</td></tr>
            </table>
        </section>
```

**Updated**

---

**Notes:** As @Jhecht correcly pointed out, the querySelectorAll returns a NodeList that needs to be iterated. The easiest way to do that, is through the forEach method available to the NodeList object. The code would be written like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".changeable").forEach(function(element){

    element.addEventListener( "dblclick", function(){ /* CODE HERE */ } );  

});
```

If you see trying to attach multiple event listeners to a web page, you should reconsider your choice and instead attach a single event listener on a parent object which will be receiving all the events of its inner children. I applied this pattern in my solution.

---

Since the question has been updated, and the intentions are more clear, I am adding another code that enables the user to double click on the `Click to translate` area and allow them to enter a custom value:

```js
document.querySelector("table").addEventListener("dblclick", function(e){
  if ( e.target.classList.contains("changeable")){
    e.target.setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
    if ( e.target.textContent === "Click to translate" ){
      e.target.textContent = "";
      e.target.focus();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<section class="allEnglishSections">
    <h2>Conditioning</h2>
    <table>
        <tr><th>English</th><th>Greek</th></tr>
        <tr><td>if</td><td class="changeable">Click to translate</td></tr>
        <tr><td>than</td><td class="changeable">Click to translate</td></tr>
        <tr><td>else</td><td class="changeable">Click to translate</td></tr>
    </table>
</section>
```

Comment: Hello; thank you dearly; please consider what if want to build the dictionary directly in the HTML file, without inserting it in JS; say you create a dictionary of 1000 words, I assume you might no want to enlarge the JS file with about extra non JS lines.

Comment: @ShadowyShade You should know that it is not possible to update or save the HTML file directly via JavaScript. You will need some kind of backend code in order to do that. The preferred way, is to save this kind of dictionary data in a backend data storage, preferably in JSON format. Then, once you load your HTML, you will also load the JSON data (dictionary of translated words) and this data will be translated into HTML table rows. This saves you significant space and also makes it easier to work with this kind of application architecture.

Comment: Alternatively, JavaScript enables you to create an HTML page on-the-fly and download it via some kind of button or click handler. I don't really know if this helps you, but it's also a possibility. I would go with creating somekind of backend code though.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `getElementById`.

```js
const if_in_greek = document.getElementById('translate-if');
const than_in_greek = document.getElementById('translate-than');
const else_in_greek = document.getElementById('translate-else');

if_in_greek.ondblclick = function() {
  if_in_greek.innerHTML = "Translation of IF goes here"
}

than_in_greek.ondblclick = function() {
  than_in_greek.innerHTML = "Translation of THAN goes here"
}

else_in_greek.ondblclick = function() {
  else_in_greek.innerHTML = "Translation of ELSE goes here"
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section class="allEnglishSections">
  <h2>Conditioning</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>English</th>
      <th>Greek</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>if</td>
      <td id="translate-if">Click to translate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>than</td>
      <td id="translate-than">Click to translate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>else</td>
      <td id="translate-else">Click to translate</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var $TABLE = $('#table');
var $BTN = $('#export-btn');
var $EXPORT = $('#export');

$('.table-add').click(function () {
  var $clone = $TABLE.find('tr.hide').clone(true).removeClass('hide table-line');
  $TABLE.find('table').append($clone);
});

$('.table-remove').click(function () {
  $(this).parents('tr').detach();
});

$('.table-up').click(function () {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  if ($row.index() === 1) return; // Don't go above the header
  $row.prev().before($row.get(0));
});

$('.table-down').click(function () {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  $row.next().after($row.get(0));
});

// A few jQuery helpers for exporting only
jQuery.fn.pop = [].pop;
jQuery.fn.shift = [].shift;

$BTN.click(function () {
  var $rows = $TABLE.find('tr:not(:hidden)');
  var headers = [];
  var data = [];
  
  // Get the headers (add special header logic here)
  $($rows.shift()).find('th:not(:empty)').each(function () {
    headers.push($(this).text().toLowerCase());
  });
  
  // Turn all existing rows into a loopable array
  $rows.each(function () {
    var $td = $(this).find('td');
    var h = {};
    
    // Use the headers from earlier to name our hash keys
    headers.forEach(function (header, i) {
      h[header] = $td.eq(i).text();   
    });
    
    data.push(h);
  });
  
  // Output the result
  $EXPORT.text(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

```css
.table-editable {
  position: relative;
  
  .glyphicon {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>HTML5 Editable Table</h1>
  <p>Through the powers of <strong>contenteditable</strong> and some simple jQuery you can easily create a custom editable table. No need for a robust JavaScript library anymore these days.</p>
  
  <ul>
    <li>An editable table that exports a hash array. Dynamically compiles rows from headers</li> 
    <li>Simple / powerful features such as add row, remove row, move row up/down.</li>
  </ul>
  
  <div border="1" id="table" class="table-editable">
    <span class="table-add glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    <table style="border: 1px solid black;" class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true">Stir Fry</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-up glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
          <span class="table-down glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- This is our clonable table line -->
      <tr class="hide">
        <td contenteditable="true">Untitled</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">undefined</td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-up glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
          <span class="table-down glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  
  <button id="export-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Export Data</button>
  <p id="export"></p>
</div>
```